# Gnuplot heatmap image duplicating and tilting

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I am having a little trouble with the 5.0 version of Gnuplot. I am attempting to create a heatmap from a file, but it is not properly displaying the data.

```
set table 'fileDataTest.dat'
splot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3
unset table
plot 'fileDataTest.dat' with image
```

as shown here: [Faulty heatmap plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzUNk.png)

The 'fileDataTest.dat' table is operating correctly. If I simply do this:

```
splot 'fileDataTest.dat'
```

then this plots the points just great: [Correct display of heatmap data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO3Iq.png)

But it has issues with the "plot ---- image" command. I have tried to diagnose the problem, but have been unsuccessful. Can you find any reason why?

The 'fileDataTest.dat' includes this:

```
# Surface 0 of 1 surface
# Curve title:
# IsoCurve 0, 10 points
# x y z type
 2000  1 -6.89386 i
 2000  2 -13.7877 i
 2000  3 -20.6816 i
 2000  4 -27.5755 i
 2000  5 -34.4693 i
 2000  6 -41.3632 i
 2000  7 -48.2571 i
 2000  8 -55.1509 i
 2000  9 -62.0448 i
 2000  10 -68.9386 i

# IsoCurve 1, 10 points
# x y z type
 1900  1 -5.59006 i
 1900  2 -11.1801 i
 1900  3 -16.7702 i
 1900  4 -22.3602 i
 1900  5 -27.9503 i
 1900  6 -33.5403 i
 1900  7 -39.1304 i
 1900  8 -44.7205 i
 1900  9 -50.3105 i
 1900  10 -55.9006 i
...  
# IsoCurve 18, 10 points
# x y z type
 200  1  1.65858e-005 i
 200  2  3.31717e-005 i
 200  3  4.97575e-005 i
 200  4  6.63434e-005 i
 200  5  8.29292e-005 i
 200  6  9.95151e-005 i
 200  7  0.000116101 i
 200  8  0.000132687 i
 200  9  0.000149273 i
 200  10  0.000165858 i

# IsoCurve 19, 10 points
# x y z type
 100  1  4.56005e-012 i
 100  2  9.1201e-012 i
 100  3  1.36802e-011 i
 100  4  1.82402e-011 i
 100  5  2.28003e-011 i
 100  6  2.73603e-011 i
 100  7  3.19204e-011 i
 100  8  3.64804e-011 i
 100  9  4.10405e-011 i
 100  10  4.56005e-011 i
```

Comment: Which patchlevel?http://www.sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1767

Comment: Version 5.0 patchlevel 3.

Does the link clarify that it should be working properly?